# Home page is not translating into another language

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html, wpml

I am using WPML plug-in for my WordPress website. My other pages are able to translate properly, but the home page is not translating.

I have my home page manually translated and published as well. When I click on  the language selector on language bar, it refreshes the page but doesn't translate to another language. But when I click on language select bar to translate other page, it does translate.

Any suggestions! I am beginner.

For reference please click here https://celebreak.eu/

Comment: are you set your translated page as homepage?

Comment: Nope, my homepage is in English and i want it to be translate into different languages (e.g. Spanish, Italian, German and French) according to user preference.

Comment: for example Im using a Polylang, and there's is very simple option for page. You made a template with one language and with other, set these 2 pages as homepages and then you select which one is homepage and you have a homepage in 2 languages.

Comment: WPML is user-friendly and it's more convenient for me to use. I am facing only homepage translation problem otherwise WPML is a good plug-in to use on WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a redirect problem, i.e. probably something in your .htaccess file...

The spanish URL for your homepage (https://celebreak.eu/es/) redirects to https://celebreak.eu/es/media/los-mejores-10-campos-entreno-futbol-del-mundo/ which is then redirected to your default (english) homepage...

I'd have a look at your virtual host definition and/or .htaccess file...

Hope this helps!